# Pandoc citation in figure caption and alt text

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll, pandoc, jekyll-extensions

I am using jekyll with pandoc markdown [plugin](https://github.com/dsanson/jekyll-pandoc-plugin) to render [citations](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#citation-rendering) in static html pages. This works well with markdown text, but does not seem to work in figure captions that are transformed into alt-text in the final html.

Markdown example with a figure that needs citation in its caption (bibliography keys such as bibkey2013 are stored in a bibtex file that is specified in jekyll configuration options):

```
![Caption text with a citation [@bibkey2013] that does not get processed by pandoc.](figure-image-file.png)
```

My attempts to include latex commands inside the caption did not work either. Any suggestions on how to have pandoc process citations inside the caption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a pandoc issue, unrelated to the jekyll plugin. Newer pandoc version (1.11.1) renders citations in figure captions properly.